# PHP: I want to redirect to another page and submit the value of the item the user clicked on

Tags: php

```
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row["StkCode"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["StkDescription"]. "</td>
            <td>" . "Eur". $row["Price"]. "</td>
            <td>" . "<img src='".$row['SmallImage']."' />".  "</td>
            <td>" . "<b id ='logout'> <input name='submit' type='submit' value=' Search '></b>". "</td>
            <td>" ."</td>
           </tr>";
```

Comment: The data is in a table, and when a user click on the row, I redirect to another page and post the value

Comment: Please use the `edit` link below your question to revise it. Use proper code formatting so that it is readable and add _all_ details to the question itself, not in comments. Ask a clear question that can be answered.

Comment: Formatted code, question still requires improvement from OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use:`header('Location: postingpage.php')` to navigate to a different page in php. In order to store values of the row you selected and be able to use them on different pages you could store the values in $_SESSION variables stored in the $_SESSION array.

For example:

```
session_start();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 $_SESSION['StkCode'] = $row['StkCode'];
 $_SESSION['StkDescription'] = $row['StkDescription'];
 //Whatever other values you want to use
}

header('Location: postingpage.php');
```

On your postingpage.php you can now access the values in the row selected by using the $_SESSION variables you defined.

```
echo "<h2>StkCode".$_SESSION['StkCode']."</h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a link with your param and use header() to redirect.

```
header($yourLink . '?yourParam=' . $param);
```

And use param from the $_GET variable on the redirected page.

```
echo $_GET['yourParam'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row["StkCode"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["StkDescription"]. "</td>
        <td>" . "Eur". $row["Price"]. "</td>
        <td>" . "<img src='".$row['SmallImage']."' />".  "</td>
        <td>" . "<a href='pagename.php?id".$row['id']."'>Edit</a>". "</td>
        <td>" ."</td>
       </tr>";
```

It will link id with the edit page (to another page) based on that you can play with data.

In case of `POST` data instead of `GET`,

You need to create form in each row (using while)